# 'No overload for method...' error when using interop.excel method via CodeDom

Tags: c#, excel, codedom

I have referenced the library `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

And using the follow simple bit of code, I can open a workbook and select the first worksheet:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(fileName, false); 
Worksheet ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

ws.Select();

//do stuff with worksheet

wb.Close(false);
app.Quit();
```

This runs as expected without error. If however, I make the above code dynamic and compile the above snippet using the CodeDom.Compiler, then an error occurs on the select method:

> "No overload for method 'Select' takes '0' arguments"

I can get around this by making a slight change to the select instruction as so:

```
ws.Select(Missing.Value)
```

But I don't quite understand why I need to do this for this?

I've already added these references to the dynamic code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

and have set up the CodeDom compiler as so:

```
CompilerParameters compilerParams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
compilerParams.GenerateExecutable = false;
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.Dll");
compilerParams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"J:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\TestProgram\packages\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.15.0.4795.1000\lib\net20\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll");
```

but is there something else / some other setting that I'm missing please?

Comment: What are you selecting the "select" statement to do? passing null to the select works but you do know it doesnt select the sheet, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-select-method-excel

Comment: CodeDom never got a lot of love. I'd suspect that the C# CodeDom provider was never updated to understand C#4 (including named and optional parameters)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It also then deletes some rows, does some further tidying and then resaves as a CSV before it actually closes the workbook. In the regular (non-dynamic) code, this line does work, I can change the sheet selection line above it to 1, 2 or whatever, and the "ws.Select;" line will select the worksheet that ws has been set to. It doesn't work this way in the dynamic code though.

Comment: Yes, Damien - I'm getting that impression - it seems pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this working now...

Damien - you got me thinking and I looked into the CodeDom provider documentation a bit more. I couldn't find anything about versions as such but noticed that Microsoft's method for setting up the provider was slightly different from the examples that I have typically seen by others.

This was how the provider was set up before:

```
Dictionary<string, string> providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"CompilerVersion", "v3.5"}
    };
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions);
```

And this is how Microsoft has it set up in their example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=netframework-4.7

```
CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
```

This simple change allowed the code to compile without error and seemingly uses the same version of c#.

Comment: So give yourself the "Answer" (Check mark on the left), so we don't need to see this anymore :)

Comment: Thanks SlapY. I will do - I've already tried but it says that I have to wait 2 days before I can mark my own answer as the accepted one! Watch this space! :)